# Cycling through the list over and over

Tags: python

List `players` contains instances of class `Players`. I want to increase index of list by 1 for each cycle, but after it reaches last element, it should start from 0 again.

Basically, it's a poker code, where I have X amount of players, and I want them to post small blind (sb) (y amount of money) and big blind (bb) (2y amount of money) each game (cycle). Now players rotate every round. Example what I mean:

```
Example in 8 player game: 
round1: sb,bb,3,4,5,6,7,8
round2: 1,sb,bb,4,5,6,7,8
round3: 1,2,sb,bb,5,6,7,8
.........................
round8: bb,2,3,4,5,6,7,sb
.........................
Example in 2 player game:
round1: sb,bb
round2: bb,sb
round3: sb,bb
.........................
```

My code:

```
stopNext = True
while check < 10:
    newDeck = Deck()
    [player.generateCard(newDeck) for player in players] # generate cards for each player
    a, b = itertools.cycle(players), itertools.cycle(players)
    if stopNext:
        next(b, None)
        stopNext = False
    one = a.next()
    two = b.next()
    one.postSB(one.amount, sb) # for each cycle select next instance
    two.postBB(two.amount, bb) # for each cycle select next instance starting at instance
```

What I get with 2 players and sb=1, bb=2 is:

```
Next round
99 instance : <__main__.Player instance at 0x7f391cce0950>
98 instance : <__main__.Player instance at 0x7f391cce0998>
Next round
96 instance : <__main__.Player instance at 0x7f391cce0950>
96 instance : <__main__.Player instance at 0x7f391cce0950>
Next round
93 instance : <__main__.Player instance at 0x7f391cce0950>
93 instance : <__main__.Player instance at 0x7f391cce0950>
Next round
90 instance : <__main__.Player instance at 0x7f391cce0950>
90 instance : <__main__.Player instance at 0x7f391cce0950>
Next round
87 instance : <__main__.Player instance at 0x7f391cce0950>
87 instance : <__main__.Player instance at 0x7f391cce0950>
```

But I should get:

```
Next round
99
98
Next round
97
97
Next round
96
95
Next round
94
94
Next round
93
92
```

I think it's problem with how `next()` is used, as you can see, starting from 3rd, address of instance is the same always, which means it's same instance.

Answer (score 3):

You want to combine two different recipes.

- [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle), which creates an infinitely repeating iterator, and which is already part of [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).
- `pairwise`, which combines adjacent entries in an iterator as you need, with a [definition given in the itertools docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes).

We can combine these. `pairwise` works by making two new iterators out of the original one -- you need to do this so that calling `next` on one doesn't effect the other. It then advances one of them by one entry, and `izip`s them together. We call this on the `cycle`d version of the original iterator, which joins the tail back to the head, giving us an infinite version.

```
In [6]:  import itertools as itt
         def pairwise(iterable):
             "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
             a, b = itt.tee(iterable)
             next(b, None)
             return itt.izip(a, b)

In [7]:  li = [1,2,3]
         pli = pairwise(itt.cycle(li))

In [8]:  pli.next()
Out[8]:  (1, 2)

In [9]:  pli.next()
Out[9]:  (2, 3)

In [10]: pli.next()
Out[10]: (3, 1)

In [11]: # or all at once:
         list(itt.islice(pli, 5))
Out[11]: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
```

In this case, however, we can actually avoid the `tee` if we want to, and combine them in one go

```
In[20]:  import itertools as itt
         def paircycle(iterable):
             "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ... cycling back to the beginning of s"
             a, b = itt.cycle(iterable), itt.cycle(iterable)
             next(b, None)
             return itt.izip(a, b)

         li2 = [11, 12, 13]
         list(itt.islice(paircycle(li2),5))

Out[20]: [(11, 12), (12, 13), (13, 11), (11, 12), (12, 13)]
```

Comment: Yes, this looks good, but it's hard to comprehend what's going on here. Will try though :)

Comment: Thanks for informative post (I learned quite a lot), but it's not what I wanted. Sorry for confusion, but I edited my original post about what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It seems strange to me that you are redefining the cycle for each iteration of the while loop.  Try defining g and h outside the while loop, and just call the lines with `.next` inside the loop.  Then to start h from +1, call `.next` on it once before entering the loop.

Comment: Good catch, this was a mistake.

Comment: See me edit. I edited as you told, but somehow it does not work correctly. It looks good now? Maybe mistake is somewhere else?